# Suggestions on syntax to express mathematical formula concisely

Tags: c++, math, programming-languages, syntax, language-design

I am developing functional domain specific embedded language within C++ to translate formulas into working code as concisely and accurately as possible.

I posted a prototype in the comments, it is about two hundred lines long.

Right now my language looks something like this (well, actually is going to look like):

```
// implies two nested loops j=0:N, i=0,j
(range(i) < j < N)[T(i,j) = (T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)];

// implies summation over above expression
sum(range(i) < j < N))[(T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)];
```

I am looking for possible syntax improvements/extensions or just different ideas about expressing mathematical formulas as clearly and precisely as possible (in any language, not just C++).

Can you give me some syntax examples relating to my question which can be accomplished in your language of choice which consider useful.  In particular, if you have some ideas about how to translate the above code segments, I would be happy to hear them.

Thank you.

Just to clarify and give an actual formula, my short-term goal is to express the following

[image][image]

expression concisely where values in `<>` are already computed as 4-dimensional arrays.

Comment: So this is actually C++ code? Interesting idea!

Comment: @Thomas yes, I am building on top of boost phoenix

Comment: Where are you stuck regarding the implementation? I guess you know about expression templates?

Comment: @gf Thank You.  I am not stuck right now at anything particular.  I am just trying to broaden my experience with alternative styles/syntax (hence community wiki).  Yes, I do know about expression templates (actually hopefully my next project).

Comment: What problem domain is your example formula from?

Comment: @Paul it is from computational chemistry (/physics), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller%E2%80%93Plesset_perturbation_theory

Comment: @Thomas I posted an example prototype as answer, take a look if you are interested

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question. Could you clarify what degree of flexibility your formulas would need, ie. what kind of mathematical constructs would be representable? I'm thinking you've already got statistical operators, will you need infinite series, differential/integral, etc? Basically I'm trying to consider how complex a formula in your language would need to get...

Comment: @Car at this point my goal is linear algebra type stuff.
But differential calculus would be really nice (although I imagine it's pretty hard to accomplish)

Comment: Your range expression does not explicitly say "0" like in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to be writing this for the ab-initio world (which I'm guessing from your MP2 equation) you want to make it very easy and clear to express things as close to the mathematical definition that you can.

For one, I wouldn't have the complicated `range` function.  Have it define a loop, but if you want nested loops, specify them both:

So instead of

`(range(i) < j < N)[T(i,j) = (T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)];`

use

`loop(j,0,N)[loop(i,0,j)[T(i,j) = (T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)]]`

And for things like sum and product, make the syntax "inherit" from the fact that it's a loop.

So instead of

`sum(range(i) < j < N))[(T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)];`

use

`sum(j,0,n)[loop(i,0,j)[(T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)]]`

or if you need a double sum

`sum(j,0,n)[sum(i,0,j)[(T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)]]`

Since it looks like you're trying to represent quantum mechanical operators, then try to make your language constructs match the operator on a 1-1 basis as closely as possible.  That way it's easy to translate (and clear about what's being translated).

EDITED TO ADD

since you're doing quantum chemistry, then it's fairly easy (at least as syntax goes).  You define operators that always work on what's to the right of them and then the only other thing you need are parenthesis to group where an operator stops.

Einstein notation is fun where you don't specify the indices or bounds and they're implied because of convention, however that doesn't make clear code and it's harder to think about.

For sums, even if the bounds implied, they're always easy to figure out based on the context, so you should always make people specify them.

sum(i,0,n)sum(j,0,i)sum(a,-j,j)sum(b,-i,i)....

Since each operator works to the right, its variables are known, so j can know about i, a can know about i and j and b can know about i,j, and a.

From my experience with quantum chemists (I am one too!) they don't like complicated syntax that differs much from what they write.  They are happy to separate double and triple sums and integrals into a collection of singles because those are just shorthand anyway.

Symmetry isn't going to be that hard either.  It's just a collection of swaps and adds or multiplies.  I'd do something where you specify the operation which contains a list of the elements that are the same and can be swapped:

c2v(sigma_x,a,b)a+b

This says that a and b are can be considered identical particles under a c2v operation.  That means that any equation with a and b (such as the a+b after it) should be transformed into a linear combination of the c2v transformations.  the sigma_x is the operation in c2v that you want applied to your function, (a+b).  If I remember correctly, that's 1/sqrt(2)((a+b)+(b+a)).  But I don't have my symmetry book here, so that could be wrong.

Comment: yes, quantum chemistry.  I was actually aiming syntax to reproduce how formulas are written in shorthand notation with implied limits.
Operators are my next project, main difficulty with them would be to introduce some sort of symmetry mechanism

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer a more solid separation between loops.  For example, I'd prefer this alternative notation to your second example:

`sum(range(j) < N)[sum(range(i) < j)[(T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)]]`

I also find the range syntax difficult.  I think a range should be a single component.  I'd prefer something like so:

`j = range_iter(0,N)`

That would open for `range x(0,N); j = range.begin();` or alternatives I can't think up right now.

You could even:

`j = range_iter(inc(0) => exc(N));` for j iterates over [0,N).

Anyway, interesting idea.  Can your resulting functions be composed?  Can you request domain information?

Comment: actually, my example is syntactic sugar for `sum(range(i) < j, range(j) < N)`.  I think I can get composition to work, but now no, do not have that (yet).  What do you mean by domain information, matrix dimensions?

Comment: All functions have a domain and range, remember?  A function is defined as a mapping from one set, a domain, to another set, the range such that for any element in the domain there's one single element in the range that maps to it (not necessarily the reverse).

Comment: hello.
Sorry for late response.  I posted rough prototype as answer, maybe it will find it interesting.
As far as domain, I think it might possible, but that have not been implemented. composition sorts of works, but not the way I want to eventually make it look like

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for simplicity you should take the implicitness of the loops even further. E.g., something like this

```
T( i < j , j < N ) = ( T(i,j) - T(j,i) )/e(i+j)
```

will work if you rewrite the assignment operator `=` to behave normally for something like `a(i) = b(i) + c(i)` but behave like a summation for `a(i<5) = b(i) + c(i)`. Assume summation starts from 0 unless the lower limit is specified, e.g. `a(3<i<5)`, check for symbolic upper/lower limits that appear as summation indices and make double sums as necessary. If you want the syntax to force explicitness you could define a separate sum operator `s=`

```
T( i < j , j < N ) s= ( T(i,j) - T(j,i) )/e(i+j)
```

I don't think you can get any cleaner than this and still have some general purpose usability. As for your short term goal, using the notion of specifying the summation index at the same time that the index first appears you could write.

```
E_MP2 s= EV( i < n1 , j < n2 , a < n3 , b < n4 ) *
         2 ( EV(a,b,i,j) - EV(a,b,j,i) ) / ( e(i)+e(j)-e(a)-e(b) )
```

where you explicitly state that this is a sum (using `s=`) making that operator then take the summation indices and limiting values from the first instance an index appears. Specifically you could also use a syntax like (assuming now a,b fixed and i,j as per your example)

```
E_MP2 s=(i<j,j<N) EV(i,j,a,b) *
                  2 ( EV(a,b,i,j) - EV(a,b,j,i) ) / ( e(i)+e(j)-e(a)-e(b) )
```

which is quite clear notationally.

You could then go on and take this concept even further by, e.g., defining an integration operator `i=` that does the same thing. I.e. it looks for instances of variables that are marked down with limits and then proceeds to integrate the expression with respect to those variables

```
F i=(0<x<Pi) x^-1 * exp(-I x^2)
```

similarly to the summation you could specify the limit when x first occurs

```
F i= x[0,Pi]^-1 * exp(-I x^2)
```

where the square brackets serve to differentiate the notation from summation, so that you don't have to use `i=` or `s=`
 and can use both summation and integration at the same time:

```
F(i) = G(i,j<10) * x[0,inf]^-1 * H(i,j,x)
```

Comment: The last formula is just beautiful.

Comment: Thanks! The more I think about this notation the more I like it. Hmm, I've been looking for a project to teach myself python...

Comment: The only thing missing is derivation and you could use `d=` and curly braces like this: `F = Log(x{x0}/A)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Phoenix and can only make assumptions about it's capabilities.

I've always liked the way Haskell allows me to express ranges as a list comprehension. It translates nicely from the actual mathematical notation into the programming language construct.

```
[ i + j | i <- [1..10], j <- [1..10] ]
```

would end up as something like:

```
[ i + j | i = range(1,10), j = range(1,10) ]
```

Unfortunately I really don't know if something like this is even possible with Phoenix.

Answer (score 1):

```
T = T - T'/e;
```

or, if you're not operating on all of T

```
T(0:i,0:j) = T(0:i,0:j) - T(0:i,0:j)'/e(0:i,0:j)
```

Comment: fortran 90?  unfortunately I am having really hard time figuring out how to implement `:` operator in C++.  How about summation  type formulas, any particular ideas?  just slight clarification ( it is there on purpose) denominator is `e(i+j)`

Comment: @aaa: You simply can't implement that, Mark probably overlooked the *embedded* part of DSEL.

Comment: @gf oh no, this is fine.  I am looking at And interested in all syntax and styles and possibilities to expand my mind.  by the way, I have looked at ROSE as a possible crutch to implement range operator.  Do you have any feelings about that?

Comment: @aaa: Ah, now i get you - my misunderstanding :)

Comment: @Georg: Mark didn't overlook the embedded part, but has, perhaps, unrealistic expectations of the power of embedded devices.  OP asked for suggestions on syntax, that's what I provided (well, I tried).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the way you specify that "triangular" 2d range.
I'd like to see something like:

```
(i,j) in range(0..j,0..N)
```

for example, which could then lead to:

```
X = sum(f(i,j) for (i,j) in range(0..j,0..N));
```

AFAIK This is not an existing language, but since you're creating your own syntax... I'm doubtful about the ability to use j in the range expression for i, but you found a way in yours :-)

Comment: hi.  I posted rough prototype was some examples, slightly modified.  If you would like to, can you comment on changes?

Comment: this is very similar to what could be written in python using list comprehension. `X = sum([f(i,j) for i, j in zip(range(0,j),range(0,N))])` (and defining a 2D range function  to avoid zip is very easy).

Comment: @kriss: yes, I was aiming for Python syntax am still new to it so I unknowingly added the parens around i,j. Also, his need is for a 2D range where 0<i<N and 0<j<i - I'm not sure if your zip expression does that. I now think you're right that it can probably be done very cleanly in python.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how complicated those formulas will be, but if get to the point when your API looks more like that math domain than standard C++ (which is using operator overloading and template metaprogramming done quite easily), I would guess you should consider developing a Domain Specific Language (DSL). When you are trying to do it in a language (like in your case) it is called internal DSL and although it has some advantages, it has many disadvantages. You should know your requirements best, however I want to suggest you looking at tools for external DSLs, which are small external languages specialized for certain domain. Look at Jetbrains MPS and Eclipse Xtext, those are two open source tools, which can be used for rapid external DSL development.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a good read to the [Project Fortress blog](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/blog), it has some inspiring posts on mathematical concise notations for a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [expressing math formulas as they are done in LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf).  After all, LaTeX is already well-defined and well-documented in this area.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure, after all, LaTeX formulae are meant for display, not for structuring the maths...

Answer (score 0):

my prototype (still needs lots of work obviously, and comments)

```
// #include "tensor/tensor.hpp"
// #include "typename.hpp"

#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/argument.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

#define BOOST_FUSION_INVOKE_FUNCTION_OBJECT_MAX_ARITY PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT
#include <boost/fusion/functional/invocation/limits.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/functional.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/intrinsic.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector_tie.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp>

#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>

namespace range_ {
    namespace detail {

        namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
        namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

        /// undefined or implicit object
        struct undefined {};

        template<int N>
        struct index {
            // index(boost::phoenix::argument<N>) {}
            typedef phoenix::actor<phoenix::argument<N> > argument;
            argument arg() const { return argument(); }
        };

        template<typename T, typename U = void>
        struct functional {
            typedef phoenix::actor<phoenix::value<T> > type;
            static type form(const T& t) { return type(t); }
        };

        template<typename T, typename U>
        struct functional<phoenix::actor<T>, U> {
            typedef phoenix::actor<T> type;
            static type form(const T& t) { return type(t); }
        };

        template<typename T>
        struct functional<undefined,T> {
            typedef typename functional<T>::type type;
            static type form(const undefined&) { return type(T()); }
        };

        template<int N, class L, class U, class T = undefined>
        struct expression;

        template<int N, class L, class U, class C>
        struct expression {
            typedef functional<L,U> lower_function;
            typedef functional<U,L> upper_function;

            expression(const L &lower, const U& upper, const C &cdr)
                : lower_(lower), upper_(upper), cdr_(cdr) {}

            template<class E>
            expression<N, L, U, E> operator()(const E &c) const {
                return expression<N, L, U, E>(lower_,  upper_, c);
            }

            template<class F>
            void operator[](const F &f) const {
#define TEXT(z, n, text) text
#define UNDEFINED_ARGUMENTS BOOST_PP_ENUM(PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT, TEXT, undefined())
                evaluate<int>(f, fusion::make_vector(UNDEFINED_ARGUMENTS));
#undef TEXT
#undef UNDEFINED_ARGUMENTS
            }

            L lower_;
            U upper_;
            C cdr_;

            const L& left() const { return lower_; }

            const C& cdr() const {return cdr_; }

            template<typename T>
            typename functional<L,T>::type begin() const {
                return functional<L,T>::form(lower_);
            }

            template<typename T>
            typename functional<U,T>::type end() const {
                return functional<U,T>::form(upper_);
            }

            template<typename T, class F, class A>
            void evaluate(const F &f, const A &arguments) const {
                T i = this->begin<T>()(arguments);
#define AS_VECTOR(var, expr) BOOST_AUTO(var, fusion::as_vector(expr))
#define ADVANCE_C(seq) fusion::advance_c<N>(fusion::begin(seq))
                AS_VECTOR(b, fusion::erase(arguments, ADVANCE_C(arguments)));
                AS_VECTOR(a, fusion::insert_range(b, ADVANCE_C(b),
                                                  fusion::vector_tie(i)));
#undef ADVANCE_C
#undef AS_VECTOR
                while (fusion::invoke_function_object(this->end<T>(), a)) {
                    this->apply<T>(cdr_, f, a);
                    ++i;
                }
            }

            template<typename T, class E, class F, class V>
            void apply(const E &e, const F &f, const V &variables) const {
                e.template evaluate<T>(f, variables);
            }

            template<typename T, class F, class V>
            void apply(const undefined&, const F &f, const V &variables) const {
                fusion::invoke_function_object(f, fusion::as_vector(variables));
            }

        };

        template<int N, class  L, class U>
        expression<N, L, U>
        make_expression(const L &lower, const U& upper) {
            return expression<N, L, U>(lower, upper, undefined());
        }

        template<int N, class  L, class U>
        expression<N, L, U>
        make_expression(const expression<N, L, undefined> &expr, const U& right) {
            return expression<N, L, U>(expr.left(), right, undefined());
        }

        template<int N1, class L1, class U1, class T1,
                 int N2, class L2, class U2>
        expression<N2, L2, U2, expression<N1, L1, U1, T1> >
        operator,(const expression<N1, L1, U1, T1> &e1,
                  const expression<N2, L2, U2> &e2)  {
            return e2(e1);
        }

#define ARGUMENT(N) phoenix::actor<phoenix::argument<N> >
#define ACTOR_COMPOSITE(O,L,R)                                          \
        phoenix::actor<typename phoenix::as_composite<O, L, R>::type>


#define LOWER_BOUND_OPERATOR(op, eval, param)                           \
        template <typename T, int N>                                    \
        expression<N, param, undefined>                                 \
        operator op (const param& left, const index<N> &i) {            \
            return make_expression<N>(left, undefined());               \
        }


#define UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR_INDEX(op, eval, param)             \
        template <typename T, int N>                            \
        expression<N, undefined,                                \
                   ACTOR_COMPOSITE(eval, ARGUMENT(N), param)>   \
        operator op (const index<N> &i, const param& e) {       \
            return make_expression<N>(undefined(),              \
                                      (ARGUMENT(N)() op e));    \
        }

#define UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR_EXPRESSION(op, eval)                       \
        template <typename T, int N, class E>                           \
        expression<N, E, ACTOR_COMPOSITE(eval, ARGUMENT(N), T)>         \
        operator op (const expression<N, E, undefined> &left,           \
                     const T& right) {                                  \
            return make_expression(left, (ARGUMENT(N)() op right));     \
        }

#define UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR(op, eval)                                  \
        UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR_INDEX(op, eval, T)                         \
        UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR_INDEX(op, eval, phoenix::actor<T>)         \
        UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR_EXPRESSION(op, eval)

        LOWER_BOUND_OPERATOR( < , phoenix::less_eval, T)
        LOWER_BOUND_OPERATOR( < , phoenix::less_eval, phoenix::actor<T>)
        LOWER_BOUND_OPERATOR( <= , phoenix::less_equal_eval, T)
        LOWER_BOUND_OPERATOR( <= , phoenix::less_equal_eval, phoenix::actor<T>)

        UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR( < , phoenix::less_eval)
        UPPER_BOUND_OPERATOR( <= , phoenix::less_equal_eval)

    }

}


namespace index {
    using namespace boost::phoenix;
    boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<0> > const i;
    boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<1> > const j;
    boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<2> > const k;
    boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<3> > const l;

    template<int N>
    range_::detail::index<N> range(const boost::phoenix::actor<
                                   boost::phoenix::argument<N> >&) {
        return range_::detail::index<N>();
    }
    template<int N, class F>
    range_::detail::index<N> range(const boost::phoenix::actor<
                                   boost::phoenix::argument<N> >&,
                                   const F &f) {
        // return range_::detail::index<N>();
        throw std::exception("not implemented");
    }



}

int main(){

    using namespace index;

    // formula domain language rough prototype
    // stuff in brackets can be any valid phoenix lambda expression

    // physicist notation, lower bound may be implicit
    (range(i) <= j, 3 <= range(j) < 4)[std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl];

    // implicit physicist notation, not done yet
    //(range(i) < range(j) < 4)[...]

    // programmer notation, same as above , but order is reversed
    (3 <= range(j) < 4)(range(i) <= j)[std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl];

    // ignore, some early prototype for lambda tensor
    // size_t N = 4;
    // tensor::tensor<4> T(N,N,N,N);

     // tensor::function<tensor::tensor<4> > T_(T);
    // (range(j) < 4)(range(i) <= j)[std::cout << T_(i,j,0,0)];

    // (range(i) < j, range(j) < N)[T_(i,j,0,0) = T_(j,i,0,0)];
    // sum(j < val(N))[T_(i,j,0,0)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at APLish languages for inspiration. By working with the matrix/array as a whole, you can get the brevity down quite a bit. I'm going to use Q below, and unless I misread your post, your second statement can be written as:

```
sum raze (T-flip T) div e
```

To understand T minus flip T, you need to look at an example. Imagine we have T set to the following matrix:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

flip T swaps the top two dimensions, which results in:

```
0 3 6
1 4 7
2 5 8
```

So `T-flip T` is basically `T(i,j)-T(j,i)` but a lot less typing, and thus a lot less error-prone.

The `raze` reduces an array to a single dimension, so razing this:

```
0 3 6
1 4 7
2 5 8
```

turns it into this:

```
0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8
```

Finally, the `sum` is sum-over; it basically adds up all of the members of its list, so

```
sum 0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8
```

means:

```
0+3+6+1+4+7+2+5+8
```

Implementing this kind of thing in C++ isn't that difficult; you could:

```
sum(raze((T-flip(T))/e))
```

with the right level of operator overloading.

By the way, K is even more brief:

```
+/,/(T-+:T)%e
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate!

I'm sure you'll find some syntax that balances concision and clarity. However good it is, it will be vastly improved by providing encapsulation. So instead of

```
qty = sum(range(i) < j < N))[(T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j)];
```

You could have

```
Texpr = (T(i,j) - T(j,i))/e(i+j);
RangeExpr = (range(i) < j < N);
qty = sum(RangeExpr)[ Texpr ];
```

That might afford you more verbosity in the syntax.

PS: Isn't this Mathematica? [Mathematica C/C++ Language Interface](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at syntax used for [Haskell's list comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension).