# C++ auto function return type implementation [trailing-return-type]

Tags: c++, boost

Is there macro, something like BOOST_AUTO, which would allow to emulate automatic return type deduction of function in C++?

I mean something like trailing-return-type, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Alternative_function_syntax

this is what I have:

```
using namespace boost::fusion;
#define AS_VECTOR(var, expr) BOOST_AUTO(var, as_vector(expr))

AS_VECTOR(b, erase(arguments, advance_c<N>(begin(arguments))));
AS_VECTOR(a, insert_range(b, advance_c<N>(begin(b)), vector_tie(i)));

while (i < upper()(a)) 
{
    //apply<T>(*this, f, a);
    ++i;
}
#undef AS_VECTOR
```

instantiation of erase and insert_range creates really crazy templates.
So I was wondering it's possible to replace macro AS_VECTOR with function, but not having to declare return type.

complete source code is here: [Suggestions on syntax to express mathematical formula concisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898870/syntax-to-express-mathematical-formula-concisely-in-your-language-of-choice/2939922#2939922)

basically, in the above snippet, and in the definition of operator in the link above, I would ideally like to infer return type from function/operator body (since it's single-line only). I tried using BOOST_TYPEOF, however generally, I do not have control how parameters are instantiated, so that does not work.

for example, the above two macro snippet is really `replace_at`. trying to make it into a stand-alone function results in return parameter which is like 6-7 templates deep.
Doable, but very messy.

If it is not something that can be implemented, it's no big deal. right now I get by with macros, so if nothing else, I will just keep using them.

thank you

Comment: Do you mean a C++0x trailing return type + `decltype`-like solution for C++03?

Comment: @James yes, something like that.  sorry, I do not know C++0x conventions well yet

Comment: @aaa:  No problem; I just wanted to help clarify what you are seeking.  :-)

Comment: If you give a bit more concrete of an example, it would be easier to help. Boost has `BOOST_TYPEOF`, for example.

Comment: @aaa: If you don't mind, could you expand on that a bit more? What is `as_vector`? Maybe some pseudo-code of the function you'd like to have. :)

Comment: @GMan hello, I posted some explanation and link to actual file.
I hope explanations make sense, sometimes I do not perceive clarity well

Comment: Just so you know I've looked at it and I think what you have might be what you have to live with macros. Trailing return types should be impossible in C++03 no matter what magic is used, I think.

Answer (score 0):

How about boost result_of library?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of

Comment: thanks.
I have tried that, unfortunately that only works if I know beforehand to instantiate expression just from parameters, which is not my case